# What are the time limits on a 401k direct rollover?

Tags: united-states, taxes, 401k, rollover

Is there a time limit from the date you request a direct rollover from your 401k until your former employer completes the transaction? When does the 60 day rollover clock for the IRS begin?

Comment: If by direct rollover you mean a trustee-to-trustee transfer of the funds, then there is no 60-day rule. If you want to take custody of the money for 60 days before putting it into an IRA, be aware that many 401k plans will deduct 20% mandatory withholding for Federal income tax, but you will be required to make up the 20% and put the whole amount into the IRA; any shortfall will be a distribution to you  and you will also owe a 10% penalty unless you are at least 59.5 years old. Other plans will send you a check payable to the IRA account that you cannot deposit into your personal account.

Answer (score 4):

The sixty day period starts when they cut the check. The old company will be able to tell you how long it takes from your request to when they process the check.

There are two ways around this issue:

- Ask for a direct roll over. Some will do this some won't.
- Ask for the check to be made to the new 401K or a rollover IRA . You must contact the new company first to get the exact information they want on the check. It will probably include an account number.

Also make sure that you know what funds you can rollover into the new account, and what can't be rolled over.

As for how long it takes for them to generate the check, I couldn't find in the guidelines a maximum processing, though I could find rules regarding the timeliness of the deposits.